# How do you scroll one area of a page using Android's web browser?

Tags: css, android

On the iPhone, safari strips out scrollbars on divs that have overflow set to auto or scroll, but still lets the user scroll with the two-finger swipe gesture.

Using an HTC Incredible, we see the scrollbars are again missing, but we cannot figure out any gesture that allows the user to scroll.  Is there a special directive we need to add to our HTML?  This should affect zillions of websites, any time someone is trying to scroll an area of the page rather than the whole page.  Does anyone know how to enable scrolling a div using the web browser on Android phones?

Comment: Can anyone out there confirm for sure that Android does not allow an element within a web page (as opposed to the whole web page) to scroll?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you cannot do this on an Android device. I was testing the browser a few weeks ago because I wanted to make a web application for iPhone / Android and the scrollable div was just unusable on Android. Also, even if it would be a gesture with two fingers it would only work on more recent versions of Android and not on the older phones, which doesn't really solve the problem because a lot of phones are still on 1.5 and 1.6.

Comment: This just seems like a crippling defect.  So many websites have a section of a page that needs to scroll.  Also, mobile safari and android's browser are both based on webkit so it's almost a conscious decision to leave out the ability to scroll?  They strip out the scrollbars, why not just leave them in...?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this thread is old, but I think it's worth noting, for those finding this thread via a web search, that the current versions of Chrome and Firefox on Android both support scrolling within frames. Unfortunately, the popular Dolphin browser does not.